# Android button findViewById Crashes

Tags: android, button, findviewbyid

I have a problem with my simple Android code;
I want to make a simple activity in which there is a button that calls a method; I want to link this button, through its "id" (button1), to the button defined in activity_main.xml.
BUT
when I launch this I have no problems:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = new Button(this);

    button.setText("Clicca qui");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSecondActivity();//method implemented by myself.
        }
    });
    setContentView(button);
}
```

while when I launch this, it crashes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//it calls a button defined in xml
    button.setText("Clicca qui");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startSecondActivity();//method implemented by myself.
        }
    });
    setContentView(button);
}
```

The activity_main.xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Which is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Post your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: You have not declared button1 at your activity_main.xml or you need a clean/build on your project.

Comment: does it crush on application start or when you press the button?

Comment: Ok, published!
I cleaned my project but nothing!

Comment: The app crashes when it starts

Comment: Why do you have `setContentView(button);`?

Comment: @codeMagic seems to be correct..

Comment: Ok, the problem was the setContentView(button). :)

Comment: Is there any more code in your `onCreate()` or do you override `onResume()`? You definitely didn't want that there but it shouldn't have made it crash on start.

Comment: No, I didn't override onResume(). But, do you think there was a conflict between the two "setContentView()"?